# Is there any way to create tokens for every user in my platform?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, exchanges

I'd like to make a user issued tokens exchange platform.

For example, there are A tokens issued by user A and B tokens issued by user B. One A token is exchanged with Two B tokens. All users have their own tokens and tokens don't need to be exchanged with other real tokens. Because of some reason, I want to issue erc20 tokens, not virtually handle tokens and manage on my database.

**Q1**. Issuing tokens for every user is simple but naive and resource consuming solution I think. So is there any other better solution?

**Q2**. On solution is, platform issues tokens and give it to user. Whenever platform gives tokens to user, put user's data into tokens in order to identify. Is it possible?

Thanks!!